# SwiftUI load JSON file and filter it once on view load

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm trying to have a list of supported countries in my application, filter may come from a WS later on or it may stay as an array of country-codes within my code.

I'm new at SwiftUI and what I'm trying to do is filter a JSON file with all the country-names, their phone codes and their country-code, and after playing around with some code I've come to this:

```
struct CountryCodePicker: View {
    let includedCountries = ["MX", "US", "CA"]
    var countryCode = Locale.current.regionCode ?? "MX"
    let allCountries: [Country] = load("countryCodes.json")
    
    @State var countries: [Country]
    @State var showingCountriesList: Bool = false
    @State private var dialCode: String = "+1"
    @State var phoneNumber: String
    @State var isActive: Bool = false
    
    func getDialCode() -> String {
        countries = allCountries.filter {includedCountries.contains($0.code)}
        
        print(countries)
        
        for country in countries where country.code == countryCode {
            return country.dialCode
        }
        return self.dialCode
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Button(action: {
                self.showingCountriesList.toggle()
            }) {
                HStack() {
                    Image(countryCode, bundle: FlagKit.assetBundle)
                        .renderingMode(.original)
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 36, height: 24)
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                        .offset(x: 0, y: -6)
                    
                    Text(getDialCode())
                        .baselineOffset(12)
                        .foregroundColor(ColorManager.Grey500)
                        .titleStyle()
                }
            }.sheet(isPresented: $showingCountriesList) {
                CountriesList(countryList: self.countries)
            }
            UnderscoredTextField(phoneNumber: "")
        }
    }
}

struct CountryCodePicker_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        CountryCodePicker(countries: [Country(name: "United States", dialCode: "+1", code: "US")], phoneNumber: "12345678")
    }
}
```

That produces this output

[image]

And the `Country` model looks like this:

```
struct Country: Codable {
    let name: String
    let dialCode: String
    let code: String
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name = "name"
        case dialCode = "dial_code"
        case code = "code"
    }
    
    init(name: String, dialCode: String, code: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.dialCode = dialCode
        self.code = code
    }
}
```

I know it contains some extra views, but you get the idea of where this program is going, I'm getting a purple warning on the first line of `getDialCode()` stating:

```
Modifying state during view update, this will cause undefined behavior.
```

This, I believe is because it may be working now, but it may behave differently on some devices under certain circumstances.

Could anyone explain what would be the correct way of doing the country filtering? I need to send this filtered array later on to a modal view in case the user has to change their country when tapping the flag.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by moving:

```
let allCountries: [Country] = load("countryCodes.json")
let includedCountries = ["MX", "US", "CA"]

func filterCountries() -> [Country] {
    return allCountries.filter{includedCountries.contains($0.code)}
}
```

And

```
CountryCodePicker(countries: self.filterCountries())
```

To my `ContentView`

And my `CountryCodePicker` now became:

```
struct CountryCodePicker: View {
    @State var countries: [Country]
    @State private var countryCode = Locale.current.regionCode ?? "US"
    @State private var dialCode: String = "+1"
    @State private var showingCountriesList: Bool = false
    
    func getDialCode() -> String {
        for country in countries where country.code == countryCode {
            return country.dialCode
        }
        return self.dialCode
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Button(action: {
                self.showingCountriesList.toggle()
            }) {
                HStack() {
                    Image(countryCode, bundle: FlagKit.assetBundle)
                        .renderingMode(.original)
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 36, height: 24)
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                        .offset(x: 0, y: -6)
                    
                    Text(getDialCode())
                        .baselineOffset(12)
                        .foregroundColor(ColorManager.Gray200)
                        .titleStyle()
                }
            }.sheet(isPresented: $showingCountriesList) {
                CountriesList(countryList: self.countries)
            }
            UnderscoredTextField(phoneNumber: "")
        }
    }
}
```